# How we can update the key path value in IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

How can we update the key path value in indexeddb.?
Suppose i had taken "email" as key path and i want to update the other input field when we take the same email address in Indexeddb.
Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only option is to create a new object store with the updated keypath. You can do this in the onupgradeneeded handler. You would need to make the new objectstore, copy the values, and then delete the old one. (Ok, you don't *have* to delete the old one, but I would.)